# How can we move the QS asked in lync IM an expert to my organizations sharepoint 2010 portal?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, lync-2010, ucma

How to move the question asked in lync  IM an Expert as question  to sharepoint discussion board?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, MS have not released the source-code for IM an Expert. Therefore, you won't be able to modify the workings of the app.

However, there is a database involved, so a bit of digging around should reveal the questions in that. From there, you'll need to create something which uses the Sharepoint API to post to a discussion board, and either schedule a job to read questions from the database and add it via the API, or add a trigger to do the same.